# Имеет ли смысл в операторе `switch` или инструкциях `if .. else` указывать условия в порядке уменьшения возможности возникновения?

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Имеет ли смысл в операторе `switch` или инструкциях типа `if (...) ... else if (...) ... else ...` условия указывать в порядке уменьшения возможности возникновения? Т.е., например, если мы знаем, что в массиве больше троек и двоек, чем единиц, то делать такую проверку:

`if (x==3) ... else if (x==2) else ...`

, а не наоборот?

Comment: А какая разница в какую сторону? У вас же равенство проверяется, а не `x<3` или `x<2` или `x<1`  или наоборот `x>3`, `x>2`, `x>1`

Comment: Чтобы быстрее выходило

Comment: И это просто пример, может быть любое условие)

Comment: Интересно, что стандарт говорит про порядок проверки условий в if--else-else-elseif

Comment: Хорошая [статья](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem) на тему разворачивая switch в visual c++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет. Компилятор все равно будет их перемешивать.
`If`-ы компилятор может переписать в `switch`. Для `switch` компилятор может построить бинарное дерево поиска на `if`-ах.

Для такой оптимизации кода надо использовать profile-guided optimization (PGO) - компилятор сам будет смотреть какие ветви используются чаще, и располагать их в оптимальном порядке.

Comment: Или он сделает jmp из таблицы, где индексом будет проверяемое число. Статистику не собирал, но кажется что таблица встречается чуть чаще, хотя может она просто более заметна.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, таблица генерируется, если числа в `case`-выражениях можно упорядочить в непрерывный диапазон. В противном случае генерируется двоичное дерево (по крайней мере на GCC).

Answer (score 9):

Добавлю, что в процессоре есть такой модуль как `branch prediction`, который позволяет оптимизировать такого рода инструкции за счет предсказания какая ветка будет выполнена. Цитата из [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2):

> Без предсказания переходов конвейер должен дождаться выполнения
>   инструкции условного перехода, чтобы произвести следующую выборку.
>   Предсказатель переходов позволяет избежать траты времени, пытаясь
>   выяснить ответвление. Ответвление выбирается по предыдущим результатам
>   проверки условия. Предполагаемое ответвление затем загружается и
>   частично выполняется. Если затем обнаруживается, что предсказание было
>   выполнено неверно, отменяются результаты неверного ветвления и в
>   конвейер загружается правильное ответвление, производя задержку.
>   Величина задержки зависит от длины конвейера. Для процессора Intel
>   Core i7 глубина конвейера составляет 14 стадий.

Поэтому такого рода оптимизации не стоит использовать без предварительного анализа его необходимости. Используя `gcc`, есть возможность добавить подсказки для модуля `branch prediction`, например (из ядра Linux):

```
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect((x),1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect((x),0)

if (likely(condition)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Понятно, что программа выполняется на железе и быстродействие зависит не только от алгоритма, но и от аппаратуры. Однако, как мне кажется, вопрос о программной составляющей, Ведь про конкретное железо не указано. Может там просто нет блока предсказаний. Или это невозможно в современном мире?

Comment: Скорее всего, если такого модуля в процессоре нет, то мы имеем дело с очень старым или очень экзотическим процессором. Согласно той же википедии, разработки модуля велись с конца 50-х годов прошлого века. Естественно за это время появились разные типы модуля с различными возможностями. Но, к примеру:  "The Intel Pentium MMX, Pentium II and Pentium III have local branch predictors with a local 4-bit history and a local pattern history table with 16 entries for each conditional jump".  Так что в данном вопросе я бы не отделял программную и аппаратную составляющие.

Comment: А если программа выполняется на каком-нибудь дешевеньком контроллере?

Comment: Зависит от модели контроллера. Тогда необходимо проверять его спецификацию и возможности.