# && проверка условий

Tags: c++

```
bool a1,a2,a3,a4,...;
a1=false;
while (a1 && a2 && a3 && a4 && ...) {...}
```

Будут ли в цикле проверяться условия `a2,a3,a4,...` или проверка завершится сразу после проверки `a1`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Проверка завершится на первом операнде. Это гарантируется стандартом:

> `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

в вольном переводе

> Для оператора `&&` гарантируется вычисление слева-направо: второй операнд не вычисляется, если первый равен `false`.

Аналогично и для оператора `||` - если первый операнд - `true`, вычисление второго не производистя.

Это правило НЕ применяется для побитовых `&` и `|`.

Так же не выполняется для перегруженных операторов `&&`, `||` (в стандарте не нашел)

Comment: если интересно [где взять стандарт С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417797/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-c)

Comment: Если расположить условия в порядке уменьшения возможности быть `false`, я получу выигрыш?

Comment: @assaqs, да, совершенно верно. К тому же если в условиях есть функции либо громоздкие выражения, они вызываться/вычислятся не будут.

Comment: Почему тогда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478096/Оптимизация-выбора ?

Comment: там где то в стандарте была поправка, что если оператор `operator&&` перегружен, то будет вычислятся условие полностью. Но я пока не нашел ссылку на это.

Comment: @assaqs, м.б. не совсем то, что Вас сейчас интересует, но подобная техника иногда весьма удобна при работе с **указателями** `if (p && *p ...) { ... }`

Comment: @assaqs, там совсем другая ситуация, там применяется оптимизация, в целом - в `switch` и цепочке `if`-`else if` - ... `else` нужно выбрать лишь одно из условий, и компилятор делает это способом, который он считает оптимальным, на результате работы это не отразится, только на производительности.

Comment: @KoVadim, нашёл только [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/5573683)  - "built-in version of || and && use shortcut semantics. While the user defined ones do not use shortcut semantics."

Comment: @KoVadim если найдете - дайте знать. Но по идее, это вытекает из возможности задать любой возвращаемый тип для перегруженного оператора. Встроенный же оператор `&&` принимает исключительно операнды, которые могут быть преобразованы в `bool` и возвращает `bool` же. Гарантия вычислений слева направо построена именно на этом.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov таких фраз можно много по интернету найти. Интересно именно со сноской на пункт Стандарта.

Comment: @alexolut, @KoVadim в стандарте не нашел, но если посудить - поведением оператора управляем мы, и в него должны передаваться два уже вычисленных объекта. И проверил - выполняется в `msvc 12.0`

Comment: @YuriyOrlov управляем. Но до некоторой степени, например, нельзя изменить кол-во операндов, приоритеты операторов. Значение по умолчанию тоже задать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Если `a1`=`false`, то другие `&&` нет смысла проверять, поэтому проверка остановится на `a1`.

Это очень просто проверить:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool a1() {
    cout << "a1\n";
    return true;
}

bool a2() {
    cout << "a2\n";
    return true;
}

bool a3() {
    cout << "a3\n";
    return false;
}

bool a4() {
    cout << "a4\n";
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (a1() && a2() && a3() && a4()) {

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Консоль:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

Comment: какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: @assaqs Компилятор значения не имеет. Такое поведение определено стандартами.

Comment: @assaqs, `mingw`, и @Mike прав -- такое поведение одинаково для компиляторов

Comment: Если расположить условия в порядке уменьшения возможности быть `false`, я получу выигрыш?

Comment: да, вполне возможно.

Answer (score 0):

В логических операций «И» и «ИЛИ» существует один подвох. Дело в том, что они участвуют в ленивых вычислениях. В отличие от побитовых операций. Если первый операнд в операции «И» имеет значение «ложь», а первый операнд операции «ИЛИ» — «истина», то дальнейшие вычисления не производятся. Потому что они бесполезны и уже не могут изменить результата. Но побитовым операциям для вычисления результата второй операнд нужен всегда.